# Can we have Multiple select in a dropdown in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Any body have an idea how to have a multiple select in a drop down box in *Zend* framework.

- Is it possible to do that user can have more than once selection in a drop down?
- How we can do that in *Zend* form?

I will appreciate if any have knows this issue

Answer (score 1):

I think Zend Framework doesn't have such option, but you can transform regular multiple select to a dropdown.

Try this [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/) for regular `multiselect`

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can select multiples in a drop down box, But you can try.. [**Multiselect**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiselect)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to do it in a standard html page? (i.e without using zend just a normal html page).

I dont think that there is such an option to have a drop down with multi select in the standard html(dont know about HTML 5 though :) ).

So if the functionality is not available in the language of representation(HTML) itself, I dont think a that a server side framework can provide such a feature. (please enlighten me if I am wrong)

And yes you can do it on the client side for sure(javascript) as mentioned by divide by zero.